# Why is this regular expression not doing what I expect?

Tags: regex

Like basically everyone else, I only have a *passing* knowledge of regular expressions.

Even so, I thought that this would be pretty straightforward, yet it isn't working the way I think it should.

```
Section\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+([^\n]+)
```

To my eyes, the above expression should match:

- The word "Section",
- followed by one or more spaces,
- followed by some digits, a dot, and some other digits,
- followed by some more space(s),
- followed by some text not including newlines

When I test my regex at Rubular like this, why [doesn't it match *any* of these](http://rubular.com/r/OC9YUP6S0n)?

```
Section 2.1  Expenses of the Initial Public Offering  
Section 2.2  Termination of Professional Services Agreement  
Section 2.3  Individual Noteholders Fee  
Section 2.4  Proceeds to the Company  
Section 2.5  Repayment of Notes and Redemption of Preferred Stock
```

For the first time in a while, I'm aware that there's something fundamental I simply don't realize about regular expressions. Anyone care to enlighten me?

Comment: Are you using a Perl-compatible regex package?  Which language are you embedding this in?

Comment: You have non-breaking space characters (`U+00A0`) in the string. That may not work in the regex's "whitespace" modifier.

Comment: @Jonathan: You can follow the link to see that I've tried it on Rubular. I'm *assuming* (given the name) that means Ruby? Although maybe it's just done in JavaScript on the client side (I haven't bothered to check). I've also tried in my plain old text editor, [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Comment: I think Digital Plane has it right (and that his or her comment should be an answer!). Try changing the regex to just 'Section ' and you won't get any matches, either. But you will if you go in and retype the spaces in the test string.

Comment: @Digital-Plane I am very curious how you spotted that those characters were in that string.

Comment: @Paul - The regex seemed correct but didn't match, so I checked if there was some odd character in the string. @ Others - should I answer this question or just keep a comment (since Paul did get it right)?

Comment: @Digital Plane: *Right on.* Post that as an answer and I will accept it! (Incidentally, what the heck is a non-breaking white character?)

Comment: @Digital I think so.  Yours _explains_ why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Digital Plane: yes, go ahead and answer. How did you check out that odd character exactly, though? I copied and pasted the string in the [UniView tool](http://people.w3.org/rishida/scripts/uniview/) and it returned 0020 (a regular space).

Comment: If you are using something with good regex support, than `\s` includes U+00A0.  If you are not, then it does not.  Perl and ICU always work with Unicode character classes, because they are Unicode-based engines (although you might need the `unicode_strings` feature in Perl, depending on decodings).  For Python you have to use the `UNICODE` compilation flag from the `re` or `regex` modules. For Java 7 you have to use `UNICODE_CHARARACTER_CLASSES` flag from the `Pattern` class. For PCRE it really depends. Last I checked Ruby didn’t handle Unicode character classes at all.

Comment: @Dan Tao: **Never test regexes using tools you find on the web!!**  Who knows what rules their engines are using? Test them only with your own tool that you are going to be using. You can do this from the command line with most of them, although for pre-compiled languages it’s annoying so you end up writing a tester program. If you are using Javascript, though, you are doomed, because its regexes are the worst of any language out there.

Comment: @Paul Equis: It is very easy to see invisible characters! Just grab them with your mouse and paste them into something like [uniquote](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniquote), which is a Unicode-aware `cat -v` or `od` equivalent, and which by default works on UTF-8.

Comment: @tchrist: You're assuming I'm using this regular expression in a software program. Really, I was just trying to do some quick manipulations in my text editor and figured the SO community would be the best source of knowledge on the subject (and check it out: I was right!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have non-breaking space characters (`U+00A0`) in the string. That may not work in the regex's "whitespace" modifier.

These non-breaking space characters are used in markup (such as HTML: `&nbsp;`) to indicate that an automatic line break should not be inserted.

[Wikipedia Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

Comment: Java in particular is bad at this: they unilaterally undid the sense of `\s` to dis-include U+00A0. If your engine missed U+00A0 with `\s`, then it is buggy. They recently fixed it in Java, but only with Java 7 can this be made to work right. Perl sometimes can miss it due to “The Unicode Bug”, finally banished in v5.14.  All the rest tend to be even worse.

Answer (score 4):

Using the link you provided, I noticed that if you "replace" the spaces on a line in your sample text (with spaces), then the regex matches.  It looks almost like a bug in that regex checker?

To see what I mean, leave the sample there, and just use `\s+`  as your regex.  It doesn't match every space.  I am not sure why typing in replacement spaces works, though.

Comment: Good call! I think Digital Plane totally nailed it in a comment: apparently the source text has `U+00A0` characters in it.

Comment: I got that behaviour too; maybe the trouble is that the characters are not recognized as spaces, as in the comment...

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, it works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = ( "Section 2.1  Expenses of the Initial Public Offering",
             "Section 2.2  Termination of Professional Services Agreement",
             "Section 2.3  Individual Noteholders Fee",
             "Section 2.4  Proceeds to the Company",
             "Section 2.5  Repayment of Notes and Redemption of Preferred Stock",
           );

foreach my $item (@list)
{
    print "$item:\n($1) <<$2>>\n" if ($item =~ m/Section\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+([^\n]+)/);
}
```

Output:

```
Section 2.1  Expenses of the Initial Public Offering:
(2.1) <<Expenses of the Initial Public Offering>>
Section 2.2  Termination of Professional Services Agreement:
(2.2) <<Termination of Professional Services Agreement>>
Section 2.3  Individual Noteholders Fee:
(2.3) <<Individual Noteholders Fee>>
Section 2.4  Proceeds to the Company:
(2.4) <<Proceeds to the Company>>
Section 2.5  Repayment of Notes and Redemption of Preferred Stock:
(2.5) <<Repayment of Notes and Redemption of Preferred Stock>>
```

That leads me to infer that you are not using Perl, or you are using Perl but didn't embed the expression into a match properly.  Of the two, I think it is more likely that you are not using Perl.

---

I adapted the Perl script to read from standard input.

```
while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    print "$_:\n";
    print "($1) <<$2>>\n" if ($_ =~ m/Section\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+([^\n]+)/);
}
```

When I supplied standard input containing UTF-8 U+00A0 (0xC2 0xA0) in place of spaces, then Perl 5.14.1 on MacOS X 10.7.1 does not recognize the regular expressions either.  However, it did work as expected when I tweaked the script to include this line before the `while` loop:

```
binmode(STDIN, ':utf8');
```

Comment: @Dan Tao: Well, that is what you get then. :)

Comment: @Jonathan: I have become so used to running with my `PERL_UNICODE` envariable set to `S` that I forget sometimes people feed UTF-8 that gets interpreted as binary due to a lack of encoding foo.  Even raw undecoded Latin-1 can miss \xA0 if you don’t have the `unicode_strings` feature enabled.  A `use v5.12` or better does that automatically for you.

Comment: @tchrist: I tried `use 5.012;` and `use v5.12;` without the `binmode` and neither recognized the strings (and neither did `use feature 'unicode_strings;`).  Without any specific Perl version but with `binmode`, it did recognize the characters.  I'm not sure whether that means I configured my Perl weirdly, or ...

Comment: @Jonathan: It depends on whether you are reading Latin-1 or UTF-8.  If it is Latin-1 as bytes, then the version dependent thing should work. But if it is UTF-8 and you don’t have `PERL_UNICODE` set to `S` for stdin (recommended) and/or `D` for files (*not* recommended except on an as-needed per-command basis), then sure, you have to `binmode` it.  The Latin-1 works because its code points coincide with Unicode’s, but only if you tell Perl it is text not binary. The version stuff does that, so you can use `"\xA0"` in your program and get that, too.

Comment: The file was fed to Perl by shell I/O redirection; it was UTF-8 (with no BOM - it isn't needed, _pace_ M$).  More precisely, it was a file of Latin-1 with every space 0x20 replaced by the two-byte 0xC2 0xA0 pair.  I did not set `PERL_UNICODE` at all.  Given what you say, I think the behaviour I was seeing is what you would expect.